# Which interpreter is used by ipython?

Tags: python

How check which python interpreter is used by a given python shell such as `ipython` or `bpython` ?
Are these shells just relying on a notion of *default interpreter* installed on the system, which I guess is `cpython` available for example at `/usr/bin/python3`?

Note: I was not able to find existing questions dealing with the difference between the python interpreter and the python shell. Maybe this question could be enlarged to integrate this difference.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand your problem but if you are in a python shell, you can retrieve the path of the binary by checking `sys.executable`

Comment: What do you mean by "the Python shell"? If you run `python` then whichever command that points to (maybe `/usr/local/bin/ipython` or `/usr/bin/python3.6`) will be run and enter its interactive mode.

Comment: Question feels unclear, but `python -V` for python version, `python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_implementation())"` for python implementation, and `which python` for python installation used (on most OSs)

Comment: To clarify my question, to me `/usr/local/bin/ipython` (for example) is just a shell allowing to type python code. This code is then interpreted by the interpreter. My question is, does ipython uses `/usr/bin/python3.6` for interpreting ? Am I more clear now ?

Comment: @ThR37 launching `/usr/local/bin/ipython` and looking at `sys.executable` gives me `/usr/bin/python3`, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Chris_Rands `platform.python_implementation()` is exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, I don't see why my question has been down vote, is it more clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the shell you are using.

On Linux/bash, you can use the command:
`which python`
that may answer `/usr/bin/python`

Then a `ls -l /usr/bin/python` may give:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 sept. 17  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7`

An other way is to launch `python` in your shell, you may get something like:

```
Python 3.8.0rc1 (default, Oct  1 2019, 21:48:24) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Or use the command `python --version`

Comment: This is not what I am asking for. I edited slightly my question to make it more clear.